# MKLocalPointsOfInterestRequest does not return the same results than MKLocalSearch.Request or MKLocalSearchCompleter

Tags: ios, mapkit, core-location, apple-maps

My app uses Core Location to request for Points Of Interest near the user. I used the different APIs provided by Apple: `MKLocalPointsOfInterestRequest`, `MKLocalSearch.Request` and `MKLocalSearchCompleter`. They do not provide the same results at all, whereas the configurations for the requests are very similar.

The `MKLocalPointsOfInterestRequest` provides very few places (if any, sometimes `The operation couldn’t be completed. (MKErrorDomain error 4.)` The others give more results but not identical. The code for the different requests is provided below.

1. Is this the expected behaviour?
2. If no, have I missed something?
3. Is this a bug?

Thanks

*PS: Tested on Xcode 14.3, iOS 16.0.*

#### **MKLocalPointsOfInterestRequest**

```swift
let center: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(41.38891, 9.16205)

let poiRequest: MKLocalPointsOfInterestRequest = MKLocalPointsOfInterestRequest(center: coordinate, radius: 3_000)
poiRequest.pointOfInterestFilter = MKPointOfInterestFilter(including: [.beach, .marina])
let poiSearch: MKLocalSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: poiRequest)
let resultsPOI = try await poiSearch.start()
print(resultsPOI.mapItems.compactMap(\.name))
```

This give me the following result:

```swift
["Plage de Stagnolu"]
```

#### **MKLocalSearch.Request**

```swift
let center: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(41.38891, 9.16205)

let searchRequest: MKLocalSearch.Request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
searchRequest.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 4_000, longitudinalMeters: 4_000)
searchRequest.pointOfInterestFilter = MKPointOfInterestFilter(including: [.beach, .marina])
searchRequest.resultTypes = .pointOfInterest
searchRequest.naturalLanguageQuery = "beach"
let search: MKLocalSearch = MKLocalSearch(request: searchRequest)
let results = try? await search.start()
print(results.mapItems.compactMap(\.name))
```

This give me se following results.

```swift
["Plage du Petit Sperone", "Plage de 3 Pointes", "Plage de Saint-Antoine Bonifacio", "Plage de Fazzio", "Piantarella Beach", "Plage du Grand Sperone", "Capu Testagro", "Plage de Balistra", "Plage de Stagnolo", "Plage de Cala Longa", "Plage de La Tonnara", "Plage Porto Novo", "Plage de Sant\'Amanza", "Rena Majori", "Plage de Rondinara", "Plage de Santa Giulia", "Spiaggia Rena Bianca", "Plage De Roccapina", "Cala Spinosa", "Naracu Nieddu Beach", "Porto Cervo Beach", "Lido Dog Beach", "Plage de Figari", "Capocchia Du Purpu", "Spiaggia Zia Culumba"]
```

#### **MKLocalSearchCompleter**

```swift
func search(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    completer.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, latitudinalMeters: 4_000, longitudinalMeters: 4_000)
    completer.pointOfInterestFilter = MKPointOfInterestFilter(including: [.beach, .marina])
    completer.resultTypes = .pointOfInterest
    completer.queryFragment = "beach"
}

func completerDidUpdateResults(_ completer: MKLocalSearchCompleter) {
    print(completer.results.map(\.title))
}
```

This give me the following result:

```swift
["Porto Istana Beach", "Sandbanks Beach", "Spiaggia La Cinta", "Piantarella Beach", "Platja de la Barceloneta", "Whitstable Beach", "West Wittering Beach", "Cala Millor", "Maora B\'ch Sailing Club"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The maxRadius in MKLocalPointsOfInterestRequest is fixed at 2000 meters.  Therefore you won't get any hits beyond that distance from your center point, regardless of the search region provided.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).